# Error 500 when submitting PHP form to database

Tags: php, sql, forms, postgresql, heroku

I have created an SQL database using ProgreSQL with Heroku for my Facebook web app, the following code is the form to collect the data

```
</style>
  <div class="container">
  <form action="insert.php" method="post" onSubmit="window.location.reload()">
  Cover URL: <input type="text" name="Cover URL" id="coverURL"><br><br>
  Title:   <input type="text" name="Title" id="title"><br><br>
  Author:      <input type="text" name="Author" id="author"><br><br>
  Genre:<br> <select name="genre" id="genre">
  <option>Adventure & Action</option>
  <option>Anthologies</option>
  <option>Classics</option>
  <option>Sport</option>
  <option>War</option>
//More options in actual code, just deleted some to save space.          
    </select><br><br>
  Total Pages: <input type="number" name="TotalPages" id="totalpages"><br><br>
  Curent Page: <input type="number" name="CurrentPage" id="currentpage"><br><br>
  <input type="submit"> </form><br><br></div>

  </center>
</section>
```

That then calls `insert.php`

```
<?php
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=ec2-54-243-190-226.compute-1.amazonaws.com port=5432    dbname=d6fh4g6l0l6gvb user=[REMOVED] password=[REMOVED] sslmode=require options='--client_encoding=UTF8'") 
or     die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());


pg_query("INSERT INTO books(coverURL, title, author, genre, currentPg, totalPg)     VALUES('"$_POST["coverURL"]"','"$_POST["title"]"','"$_POST["author"]"','"$_POST["genre"]"',    '"$_POST["currentpages"]"','"$_POST["totalpages"]"')");


pg_close($dbconn);
?>
```

The problem is I get error 500 when I hit submit, after looking around online most solutions say there must be an error in the PHP, but due to my inexperience (learning this as I go) I have no idea what I've done wrong.

I can provide more information if necessary. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your server log say?

Comment: your database is connected or not...1st check that

Comment: @thumbernirmal how do I check that? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm very new to this.

Comment: check in if condition if($con){ echo "connet"; }else{echo "disconnect"; } and check output

Comment: Try to narrow the code down to <?php $dbconn = pg_connect("host=ec2-54-243-190-226.compute-1.amazonaws.com port=5432"); ?> Does this work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Please make sure the `names` of the html inputs **match** the `$_POST` values.

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO books(coverURL, title, author, genre, currentPg, totalPg) VALUES('".$_POST["coverURL"]."','".$_POST["title"]."','".$_POST["author"]."','".$_POST["genre"]."','".$_POST["currentpages"]."','".$_POST["totalpages"]."')");
```

EDIT: use this statement ------^

And instead of:

```
'$_POST[author]'
```

It is better to do them like this:

```
'".$_POST["author"]."'
```

And also are you aware that `$sql` isnt actually being inserted into the db?

Comment: Thanks, I've added the extra quote symbols as suggested. I wasn't aware that $sql isn't being inserted, I got the majority of the code from here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp what am I missing?

Comment: no worries! in future try not to use w3schools:) [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com) Ill update my answer to what you need to do

Comment: okay I've changed a few things (edited them above) and ensured all `"` and `'` are correct. I'm now getting this error in my logs:

`PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /app/www/insert.php on line 6, referer:[address]/new.php`

Comment: If the code you have in your question is the latest, you have a duplicate `;`

Comment: Deleted that but it didn't seem to be the problem, still getting the same error from the logs.

Comment: file with the form(new.php): http://pastebin.com/R03HHqUv

file the form calls(insert.php): http://pastebin.com/vfe5eYuN

Comment: That did the trick, but my log is now giving me `Query failed: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""\nLINE 1: ...rentpg, totalpg) VALUES('','','','Adventure & Action','','')\n
      ^ in /app/www/insert.php on line 4, referer: [address]/new.php` I had a look online but couldn't find a solution. Is this trying to store a string in an int or something like that?

(By the way, thank you ever so much for your help!)

Comment: thats okay! try just putting `1` instead of `Adventure & Action`

Comment: That seems to have helped, as now everything but the last 2 values are passing in. It doesn't seem to like number fields. `Query failed: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""\nLINE 1: ... VALUES('www.example.jpg','title','author','Classics','','')\n` I have tried changing `input type="number"` in the form to `input type="integer"` but that gives the exact same error in the log

Comment: if the last two columns are `INT` set them as `TEXT` and vice versa to see what happens

Comment: I haven't quite got it working, but it saves to the database successfully. Can't thank you enough! You may have saved my dissertation :D

Answer (score 0):

An [error 500 is a "internal server error"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). This basically means that something on the server side has failed, it's just a very generic error message. Basically it can be everything, it's not only limited to your script. It could be a Apache module error or anything else that refuses your WebServer software to handle the request without any fatal failures.

If it only occurs on the same actions (like submitting a form or calling a special page) it's very likely it's a script error causing the error 500.

You should look up your log files, esp. the apache error log. It should contain further informations on what has gone wrong.

In your case, maybe your sever is not allowed to connect to an external database server, but it's only a guess.

Comment: After editing the code a little, I checked the logs and I'm getting this: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /app/www/insert.php on line 7, referer: [address]/new.php`

What could be causing that?

Comment: UPDATE: changed `$_POST["coverURL"]` etc to `$_POST[coverURL]`, now the log just has lots of  `GET \favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304. still getting error 500.

Comment: Good, it means there is a syntax error somewhere. What exactly is on line 7?

Comment: `$_POST[coverURL]` is wrong.. it's an associative array, it must be in strings: `$_POST["coverURL"]` or `$_POST['coverURL']`.

Comment: oops! okay I readded the " symbols, line 7 is:

`VALUES('$_POST["coverURL"]','$_POST["title"]','$_POST["author"]','$_POST["genre"]','$_POST["currentpages"]','$_POST["totalpages"]')");
`

Comment: Ok, then it's because you are starting the whole string with `"` and using `"` within it, too. That won't work. Have you tried chriz' answer? This should eliminate the parse error.

Comment: I've double checked to make sure all my `"` and `'` symbols are correct as in chriz' answer, I now get a different parse error.

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /app/www/insert.php on line 6, referer:[address]/new.php`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're really "mixing" things together. Your code connects with pg_connect and querying with mysqli.  Use only Postgree functions to connect to the database Read manual at http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pgsql.php.

I would do something like: (I have not tested it though)

```
 <?php
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=ec2-54-243-190-226.compute-1.amazonaws.com port=5432    dbname=d6fh4g6l0l6gvb user=[REMOVED] password=[REMOVED] sslmode=require options='--client_encoding=UTF8'") or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());;

$coverUrl = $_POST["coverURL"];
$title = $_POST["title"];
$author = $_POST["author"];
$genre = $_POST["genre"];
$currentPages = $_POST["currentpages"];
$totalPages = $_POST["totalpages"];
pg_query_params($dbconn, "INSERT INTO books(coverURL, title, author, genre, currentPg, totalPg) VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)", array($coverUrl, $title, $author, $genre, $currentPages, $totalPages));

pg_close($dbconn);
?>
```

Comment: just replaced `mysqli_query` with `pg_query` and `mysqli_close` with `pg_close` but I'm still getting error 500.

Comment: I've supplied with an example. I hope it will help. I am no postgree expert and I've actually never used it, but I think the code will work.